# Create an RXJS interrupt timer

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Right now I have a display variable that is updated with the value of a stream. Super simple:

```
display$
    .distinctUntilChange()
    .subscribe((val) => this.display = val);
```

I also have an "interrupt" message functionality that will change `this.display` to the passed in value for 2 seconds and then revert it back, using a `setTimeout`. I want to change this part to use streams. So whenever a value comes in on my interrupt$ stream it changes the display value for 2 seconds before going back to whatever the latest message on display$.

My attempt at diagraming it:

```
display$    --A-----C----------->
interrupt$  ----B----D-|----|--->
final       --A-B----D------C--->
```

I have two "end" markers on the interrupt stream to try and signify when the timer is up that would revert it back to display$. Current non rx code cancels the B timer as soon as D comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// mock streams
const [display$, interrupt$] = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('button'))
  .map((b, i) =>
    Rx.Observable.fromEvent(b, 'click')
    .map((e, idx) => `${i === 0 ? 'DISPLAY' : 'INTERRUPT'}-${idx}`)
  )

Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
    display$,
    interrupt$.startWith(null)
    .switchMap(v => Rx.Observable.of(v)
      .merge(Rx.Observable.of(null).delay(2000))
    )
  )
  .map(([d, i]) => i || d)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .do(x => console.log(x))
  .subscribe()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.js"></script>

<button>display</button>
<button>interrupt</button>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks man, that switchMap and merging a delay is what I couldn't quite wrap my head around. Makes so much sense now that I look at it.

Comment: Glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based on truning `display$` into a hot observable

```js
console.clear() 
const Observable = Rx.Observable

const display$ = Observable.merge(
  Observable.of('A').delay(20),
  Observable.of('C').delay(70),
)

const interrupt$ = Observable.merge(
  Observable.of('B').delay(40),
  Observable.of('D').delay(80),
)

const delayed$ = interrupt$
  .delay(2000)
  .withLatestFrom(display$)
  .map(([i,d]) => d)
  .last(x => x)

const offSignal$ = interrupt$.map(x => false).publish().refCount() 
const onSignal$ = delayed$.map(x => true).startWith(true).publish().refCount() 
const displayHot$ = display$.publish()
const displayOut$ = onSignal$.flatMap(() => displayHot$.takeUntil(offSignal$))
displayHot$.connect()

const output = Observable.merge(
  displayOut$.map(x => 'display:'+x), 
  interrupt$.map(x => 'interrupt:'+x), 
  delayed$.map(x => 'delayed:'+x)
)

const start = new Date()
output.timestamp().subscribe(x => console.log(`Value: ${x.value}, elapsed: ${x.timestamp-start}`))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.js"></script>
```